# How do I scrape data from property tax website

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I want to scrape a few things from this page http://bexar.trueautomation.com/clientdb/Property.aspx?cid=110&prop_id=1229623

1. I want the Property ID: under the Property table
2. Sqft and Market Value under the Land Table
3. Impprovement #1 under Improvement / Building

and running into a few issues

1. I can't find any combo of elementID or tag/class name to pull this info
2. Same as above
3. I only want to pull the first item in the list and adding (0) to multiple spots in my code below isn't working to make this happen

I was thinking the best way to do this is make a sub ProcessHTMLPage ProcessHTMLPage2 and ProcessHTMLPage3 that does all these and then I can work on the formatting to get them into the appropriate columns as needed

```
Sub GetHTMLDocumentXML()

    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim URL As String
    Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement


    XMLPage.Open "GET", "http://bexar.trueautomation.com/clientdb/Property.aspx?cid=110&prop_id=1229623", False
    XMLPage.send

    If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox XMLPage.Status & " - " & XMLPage.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    ProcessHTMLPage2 HTMLDoc

End Sub

Sub ProcessHTMLPage2(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer

    Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByClassName("improvements")

    Cells.Clear

    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables

        Debug.Print HTMLTable.className
        RowNum = RowNum + 1

        For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            Debug.Print vbTab & HTMLRow.innerText
            ColNum = 1


            For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
                Debug.Print vbTab & HTMLCell.innerText
                Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
                ColNum = ColNum + 1

            Next HTMLCell

        Next HTMLRow
    Next HTMLTable

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: the code works for me in pulling the improvements. Since *I only want to pull the first item in the list * seems to be your only real question, just manufacture the first item by adding a counter to the `For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children` loop that stops after the first iteration. `Do ... Loop Until i = 1`

Comment: Scott thanks for the quick reply! Sorry I want to be able to pull the Property ID: under the Property table and Sqft and Market Value under the Land Table but I can't seem to figure out the elementID classname or tag name that would accomplish that.
```
Do
                Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
                i = i  + 1
Loop Until i  = 1
                ColNum = ColNum + 1
```
crashes my workbook, it puts Improvement #1: into A1 then crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to get `Property ID`,`Sqft`,`Market Value` from that webpage. I had to use hardcoded index to locate the last two elements as I could not find any specific marker.

```
Public Sub FetchInfo()
    Const Url$ = "http://bexar.trueautomation.com/clientdb/Property.aspx?cid=110&prop_id=1229623"
    Dim S$, oItem As Object
    Dim propertyId$, Sqft$, marketValue$

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        .write S
        For Each oItem In .getElementsByTagName("td")
            If InStr(oItem.innerText, "Property ID:") > 0 Then
                propertyId = oItem.NextSibling.innerText
                Exit For
            End If
        Next oItem

        Sqft = .getElementById("landDetails").getElementsByTagName("td")(4).innerText
        marketValue = .getElementById("landDetails").getElementsByTagName("td")(7).innerText

        Debug.Print propertyId, Sqft, marketValue
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked amazing, I added the following to get the other info I needed
living = .getElementById("improvementBuildingDetails").getElementsByTagName("td")(2).innerText
        Value = .getElementById("improvementBuildingDetails").getElementsByTagName("td")(3).innerText
and then put all the variables into cells, thank you so much

Comment: One more question if you don't mind, would it be easy enough to loop this through a bunch of sites lets say if the property ID is between 1000000 and 1230000 or you think that's pushing excel too far?